# How to overwrite an existing document in SharePoint Library with a new document with different name but version should be maintain?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

In a SharePoint Online Document Library (version with x.x version enabled!) I have a PDF document, let's call it doc1.pdf which I want to replace by a new version.

The new document I have is called doc2.pdf .

I did not find a way yet to upload doc2.pdf and overwrite doc1.pdf. How can I do that?

It seems that I can only overwrite the existing document, if the new one has the same name as the existing one. ?!

Please reach me nagarajan.x.elumalai@gmail.com

Comment: I dont think that is possible as when you want to overwrite a document in doc library it must have same name and extension of the file. Otherwise it will be treated as a new document

Comment: Using Code can we achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload file with the same name. renaming the old file to doc2.pdf will also enable to add version for file.

Version history tab shows all the version. Different file name is not allowed.

Comment: Using Code can we achieve this functionality?

Comment: i dont think so